# R save table as image

Tags: r, plot

I would like to export a data frame as a (png) image. I've tried with this code, but the table get clipped vertically.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

df <- data.frame(a=1:30, b=1:30)

png("test.png")
p<-tableGrob(df)
grid.arrange(p)
dev.off()
```

Is there a way to avoid this behaviour without having to set manually the size of the image?

Comment: You could also try the `xtables` package to reder it as a \LaTeX table and exporting as a PDF. It is much more customizable.

Answer (score 23):

You can change this behavior by specifying a height and width.

```
png("test.png", height=1000, width=200)
p<-tableGrob(df)
grid.arrange(p)
dev.off()
```

Anyway, it is usually not very helpful to save tables as pictures.

Comment: Is there a way to set the size of the image automatically according to the size of the table?

Comment: You could use something like `height=350*nrow(df)` and `width=80*ncol(df)`

Answer (score 18):

You can do like this:

```
library(gridExtra)
png("test.png", height = 50*nrow(df), width = 200*ncol(df))
grid.table(df)
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 0):

This works just fine:

```
library(gridExtra)

df = data.frame("variables" = c("d_agr","d_def","d_frig","d_hidro","d_roads","d_silos"),
"coeficient" = c(0.18,0.19,-0.01,-0.25,-0.17,0.09))

png("output.png", width=480,height=480,bg = "white")
grid.table(df)
dev.off()
```

Comment: this doesn't add any value to the previous answers, what's the purpose of this answer?

Answer (score 0):

To get the size of the table you have to generate a **tableGrob** first, than you can get the *height* and *width* parameters. The parameters are "grobwidth", they have to be converted into inch.

Here is my solution (base on gridExtra [vignettes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/vignettes/tableGrob.html)), it works fine for me.

```
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
gridFtable <- function(d, pd = 4, fontsize = 10, fontfamily = "PT Mono") {
    
    ## set plot theme
    t1 <- ttheme_default(padding = unit(c(pd, pd), "mm"), base_size = fontsize, base_family = fontfamily)
    
    ## character table with added row and column names
    extended_matrix <- cbind(c("", rownames(d)), rbind(colnames(d), as.matrix(d)))
    
    ## get grob values
    g <- tableGrob(extended_matrix, theme = t1)
    
    ## convert widths from grobwidth to inch
    widthsIn <- lapply(g$widths, function(x) {convertUnit(x, unitTo = "inch", valueOnly = TRUE)})
    heigthsIn <- lapply(g$heights, function(x) {convertUnit(x, unitTo = "inch", valueOnly = TRUE)})
    
    ## calculate width and height of the table
    w <- sum(unlist(widthsIn)) - 1*convertUnit(unit(pd, "mm"), unitTo = "inch", valueOnly = TRUE)
    h <- sum(unlist(heigthsIn)) - 1*convertUnit(unit(pd, "mm"), unitTo = "inch", valueOnly = TRUE)
    
    return(list(grobData = g, data = d, width = w, heigth = h, theme = t1))
}

saveTable <- gridFtable(data.frame(a=1:30, b=1:30))
png(file = "./test.png", width = saveTable$width, height = saveTable$heigth, units = "in", res = 100)
grid.newpage()
grid.table(saveTable$data, rows = NULL, theme = saveTable$theme)
dev.off()
getwd()
```