# How to make a nice looking table in base r (not markdown)

Tags: r

I’ve been looking for an hour, but everything I can find about how to make a nice looking table out of a data frame mentions that it’s for rmarkdown, html, or latex.

Is it not possible to make a nice looking table in base r?

`plot(x, y)` makes a graph.

Is there no function like:  `printTable(df)`?

Comment: I don't know about "nice", but you can use `edit(df)`

Comment: Thanks, I wasn’t aware of the edit( ) function. Maybe I’ll use that and a screenshot, if I cannot figure out another way.  But it’s definitely not nice looking.

Comment: Where do you want to view this nice looking table? Print to the console? Maybe `knitr::kable(mtcars)`. In its own window? `View(mtcars)`. Save as an image? Something else?

Comment: @Gregor, save as an image. Sorry for not being more clear.

Comment: I'd suggest [Create a PDF table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3881278/903061) as a possible duplicate. Many of the answers would work with any graphic device.

Comment: `xtabs` is maybe more "functional" than "nice-looking", but could be a step in the right direction?

Comment: @Gregor, if that link answers my question, then am I correct that the answer is “No. There is not a way in base R.”?

Comment: I think base R considers data frames as objects for calculation and manipulation of data, not visualization. The great thing about R is its package system, which extends it. Is there some reason you can only use base R ?

Comment: @neilfws, no, I can and do use packages. I’m just trying to learn about R.  If the answer is that printing nice looking tables is not a feature in base R, then someone should submit that as an answer, and I’ll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Broadly speaking over what you can get from a normal `print` in `base::print` there is not much else you can do. You could try to twist `plot` function to plot values from selected cells in a data frame but that would be very onerous to develop and impractical in the light of currently available and maintained solutions. There is a number of packages that let you achieve what you need. For instance you can try [`formattable`](https://renkun-ken.github.io/formattable/) by [renkun-ken](https://github.com/renkun-ken).

## Example

For a simple example you can try `formattable::formattable(mtcars[1:10,])`

[image: Pretty mtcars output]

---

## Creating Images

For a solution creating images from tables, have a look at [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23365096/1655567). As discussed, in the linked answer if you insist on generating a static image you can use `grid.table` function offered via [`gridExtra`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/index.html): `tbl <- grid.table(mtcars[1:5,])`.

Comment: Just so that I’m clear, my question was if there’s any base R function for rendering tables that look nice (enough to include in a report), and I’m going to infer that your answer, since you’re referring me to a package, is, “No. There is no function for that in base R.”

Comment: @Joe Hi Joes, yes that's my view. I have expanded the answer a little bit to address your valid comment.

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in the `flextable` package that is very easy to use with multiple options to create nice tables. 
You can also have multiple word, pdf, or html output types. 
I invite you to check the manual : https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/flextable/vignettes/overview.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are using lm, lmer, glm, or glmer, the package sjplot creates really nice tables. sjplot is compatable with a suite of regression model packages. The function, tab_model can be utilized to create summary outputs of one or several models at once. I find that they are almost publication ready and easy to manipulate.