# R: Save a data.table as an image with Title

Tags: r, image, dataframe, ggplot2, plot

A follow-up question to this: [R save table as image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23365096/r-save-table-as-image)

Is there any way to add **Custom Titles and Headings** to images generated by the following code?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
df <- data.table(a=1:10, b=11:20,c=21:30, d=31:40)
png("test.png")
p<-tableGrob(df)
grid.arrange(p)
dev.off()
```

The above code gives me the following output:

[image: ![enter image description here]

I want to add titles to the image and save them as files on my disk, so that I can use them in other documents and presentations.

Expecting something like this:

[image]

Or if there's a smarter way to do it in R, it would be very helpful.
Again, all I am trying to do is create tables and export them to individual image files (that have appropriate titles in the images).

Comment: This seems to be a confusion between 'creating a custom table' and 'exporting the table via png'.
Can you be more specific about what are you waiting for?

Comment: Made necessary changes to the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use grid.arrange.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(data.table)

df <- data.table(a=1:10, b=11:20,c=21:30, d=31:40)
png("test.png")
p <- tableGrob(df)
grid.arrange(top = "Title", p)
dev.off()
```

Comment: Thank you, this works but is there more efficient way of getting what I want? Maybe not use grids at all?