# Automate naming of table and export as image?

Tags: r, automation

I have this automated script that produces a table with frequencies of "thetarget" tokens by year:

```
library(quanteda)

vec <- c("Apple", "Google")    

out <- map(vec, ~ 
         df %>%
  filter(str_detect(collectionName, .x)) %>%
  filter(str_detect(Year, paste(years, collapse = "|"))) %>%
  corpus(text_field = "text") %>%
  tokens() %>%
  tokens_select(thetarget) %>%
  dfm() %>%
  dfm_group(groups = "Year") %>%
  convert(to = "data.frame")
)

names(out) <- sub("^(...).*\\s+(\\S)$", "\\1\\2", vec)
```

Using

```
 View(out$Apple)
```

Produces the corresponding table.

I am trying to automate the export of these tables as a pdf or jpeg with the name of the file being "Apple" for example.

Is there a way to do this?

TIA

Comment: rmarkdown has a pdf output type, which can take dynamic file names (https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/dynamic-yaml.html). Have a look at `KableExtra` or `gt` packages for pretty tables. As for saving data.frames as png, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23365096/r-save-table-as-image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't execute your code chunk (problem with function `convert`, from which library is it?) - but it isn't a problem.

Exist a lot of solutions, but, f.e., you can use packages `gt` or `flextable` for this task (pile of output types).

First of all, install the `webshot` and `PhantomJS`.
And after you can install other packages *(gt and flextable)*. See examples:

**(gt)**

```
tab_1 <-
    gtcars %>%
    dplyr::select(model, year, hp, trq) %>%
    dplyr::slice(1:5) %>%
    gt(rowname_col = "model") %>%
    tab_stubhead(label = "car") %>%
    gtsave("tab_1.png", expand = 10, path = "********")
```

**(flextable)**

```
   ft <- flextable(head(mtcars))
   save_as_image(x = ft, path = "********\\image_name.png")
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am using the quanteda package for "convert". I install the "gt" package and could not get it to work. Do you know if I can use the "gt" script after this line "convert(to = "data.frame")"?

Comment: @J.Doe I tried now to execute your code, but had an error: ```Error in UseMethod("filter_") :
no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "function"``` I need to read how to fix it.

Comment: Which packages do use also: ```purrr and dplyr```?

Comment: @J.Doe it is a conflict because of stats and dplyr ```filter```. I can't fix( You can give to me a fixed code or another one.

Comment: I'm using dplyr. Not using stats (I think, I'm still novice at R). The script you suggested doesn't work with dplyr?

Comment: @J.Doe Yes, see an error above, because of ```dplyr::filter() masks stats::filter()``` . But after using ```stats::filter``` one can see a new error. Did you test the functionality of this code chunk?

Comment: I've decided to export them as excel sheets and got it to work. Appreciate the help though!

Comment: @J.Doe No problems. I learned about a new interesting library ```quanteda```. It is useful for me too.